# Puppet: "puppet agent --test" on client machines. I'm not able to do ssh on master & client machines

Tags: puppet

**#/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/mymodule/manifests/init.pp**

```
class mymodule {

file { "/bin/extend_shutdown.sh":
    mode => "0644",
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/extend_shutdown.sh',
}

file { "/bin/server_shutdown.sh":
   mode =>"777",
   owner =>'root',
   group => 'root',
   source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/server_shutdown.sh',
 }
file { "/bin/user_activity.sh":
   mode =>"777",
   owner =>'root',
   group => 'root',
   source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/user_activity.sh',
 }
file { "/bin/new_cron.sh":
   mode =>"777",
   owner =>'root',
   group =>'root',
   source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/new_cron.sh',
 }

 file { "/home/azureuser/shutdown.sh":
   mode =>"777",
   owner =>'root',
   group =>'root',
   source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/shutdown.sh',
}
file { "/bin/tag.sh":
   mode => "777",
   owner => 'root',
   group => 'root',
   source =>'puppet:///modules/mymodule/tag.sh',
 }
 #file { "/etc/profile":
   #mode => "777",
   #owner => 'root',
   # group => 'root',
   #  source =>'puppet:///modules/mymodule/profile',
 # }
  file { "/etc/.bash_aliases":
   mode => "777",
   owner => 'root',
   group => 'root',
   source =>'puppet:///modules/mymodule/.bash_aliases',
 }
 #file { "/etc/profile.d/alias.sh":
 #      mode => "777",
 #     owner =>'root',
 #    group =>'root',
 #   source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/alias.sh',
 # }
 file { "/bin/max_timetrack.sh":
   mode => "777",
   owner =>'root',
   group => 'root',
   source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/max_timetrack.sh',

 }
}
```

**#azureuser@disk-bkp:/rescue/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests$ cat site.pp**

```
 node default {
    include  mymodule

    cron {'user_tracking':
        ensure  => 'present',
           command => 'bash /bin/user_activity.sh',
           hour    => ['*'],
           minute  => ['30'],
           user    => 'root',
    }
    #cron {'shutdown1':
    #    ensure  =>'present',
     #   command => 'bash /bin/server_shutdown.sh',
      #  hour    => ['*'],
       # minute  => ['*/15'],
       # user    => 'azureuser',
    #}
    cron {'new_cron':
       ensure  => 'present',
       command => 'bash /bin/new_cron.sh',
       hour    => ['*'],
       minute  => ['*'],
       user    => 'root',
    }

    exec {'shutdown_running_status':
      command => 'cat /var/log/syslog | grep server_shutdown.sh',
      provider => shell,
    }

    exec { 'reconfigure_cron':
      command => 'bash  /home/azureuser/test.sh',
      provider   => shell,
    }
    exec {'input.log':
       command  => 'user=`whoami`;sudo touch /usr/bin/input_${user}.log ; sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/input_${user}.log',
       provider => shell,

   }
   exec {'profile':
        command => 'echo "source /etc/.bash_aliases" >> /etc/bash.bashrc',
        path     => [ '/bin', '/sbin' , '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin' ],
        provider => 'shell',
        unless => 'cat /etc/bash.bashrc |grep -i /etc/.bash_aliases',
   }
   exec {'getting_tag':
        command => 'sudo bash /bin/tag.sh',
        path     => [ '/bin', '/sbin' , '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin' ],
        provider => 'shell',
   }
    exec {'folder_creation':
        command => 'sudo mkdir /pg',
        path     => [ '/bin', '/sbin' , '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin' ],
        provider => 'shell',
        unless => 'ls -ld /pg',
   }
   exec {'deleting_log_file':
        command => 'sudo cd /pg/; sudo rm  *',
        path     => [ '/bin', '/sbin' , '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin' ],
        provider => 'shell',
   }

}
```

The client and master work fine for one to two hours after executing `puppet agent --test` on client machines, then they break. It looks like the `/bin` folder is getting deleted.  I get this error:

> error: ubuntu@18.222.8.217: Permission denied (publickey)

I have tried same code on multiple machines but all the machines are in same sate.  What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be this:

> ```
> exec {'deleting_log_file':
>      command => 'sudo cd /pg/; sudo rm  *',
>      path     => [ '/bin', '/sbin' , '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin' ],
>      provider => 'shell',
> }
> ```

Executing a `cd` command via `sudo` does not affect the working directory of the of the host shell, so the subsequent `rm *` runs with the working directory of the Puppet agent at that time.  That is unlikely to be `/pg`, so you asked Puppet to delete different files than you intended.  It is plausible that the deleted files were the contents of `/bin`.

---

You shot yourself in the foot by a combination of several poor decisions.  In the first place, you probably would have been better off with a [`Tidy`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/tidy.html) resource instead of rolling your own with an `Exec`:

```
tidy { 'Clean out /pg':
  path    => '/pg',
  age     => 0,
  recurse => true,
  rmdirs  => false,
}
```

Take care, however, because the effect of that is not identical to your original in the event that `/pg` has subdirectories (which might or might not reflect another flaw in your version).

Having chosen an `Exec` instead, it was unnecessary to introduce `sudo` into the command.  If the agent can perform the requested action at all, then it does not need `sudo` in order to do it, as it would be running with privilege in the first place.  If Puppet were running without privilege then `sudo` would not help, because Puppet would not provide a password.  If the command had just been `cd /pg; rm *` then it would have been more likely to work.

Having chosen an `Exec`, it also was unnecessary to express the wanted operation via a compound of two commands.  It would have been simpler, clearer, and safer to instead use `rm /pg/*`.  That removes any risk of the wrong files being deleted on account of the `cd` failing or being rendered ineffective.  The general principle here is to prefer absolute paths.

Thus, if you insist on doing it with an `Exec`, then this would be better:

```
exec {'deleting_log_file':
  command  => '/bin/rm /pg/*',
  provider => 'shell',
}
```

---

Overall, your code is fairly non-idiomatic.  Puppet is not a script engine, and Puppet manifests should not be conceived of or structured as script analogues.  Among other things, use of `Exec`s should be considered somewhere between a crude hack and a last resort, and substantially all your code should be in classes in modules, not directly in node blocks.